# Image Magick error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638

Tags: python, image, imagemagick, raspberry-pi

While using image magick to shoot a series of pictures and then making a .gif using graphics magick I am getting this error every 15 times I run th epython script.

It seems like the file is being placed in another location it is not supposed to go to and is not able to retrieve it. I am not able to find a solution for this. Any help would save me a lot of banging my head on my keyboard.

```
about to set overlay_text variable1
convert: unable to open image `affect': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `affect' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert: unable to open image `the': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `the' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert: unable to open image `structure': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `structure' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
/bin/sh: 4: spammers: not found
/bin/sh: 5: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Comment: How your source images are generated ? I think you don't tell enough to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bad quoted string. Look for an unterminated quote near the term "affect the structure" & spammers.